# Setting jQuery Cookie on selected class

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I'm having trouble setting a jQuery cookie on a selected class when added to added to an element.

Here is what I have for JS:

```
//Show / Hide Goal Data
var chkIndexCookie = jQuery.cookie("nav-item-selected");
if (chkIndexCookie != "") {
    jQuery(this).addClass('+chkIndexCookie+').siblings('.showSingleBoard').removeClass('selected');
}       
jQuery('.showSingleBoard').on('click', function () {
    var navIndex = jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
    jQuery.cookie("nav-item-selected", navIndex);

    jQuery(this).addClass('selected').siblings('.showSingleBoard').removeClass('selected');
    jQuery('.analytics-board').hide();
    jQuery('.data-' + jQuery(this).data('target') + '-board').fadeIn( 1000 );
    jQuery('.data-' + jQuery(this).data('target') + '-board').addClass('active');

    if(jQuery('#board-global').is(":visible")){
        jQuery('.analytics-board').fadeIn( 1000 );
    }           
});
```

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? What the code actually do and what do you expect?

Comment: Thanks @MartinHučko basically the code adds a class of selected on the element containing class showSingleBoard"when it is clicked. I would like to set a cookie on which element has a class of selected.